# where can we find SenTestingKit framework for iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c

I am using the OAuth into my application for google services and I am getting nearly 30 errors regarding to the SenTestingKit framework.Can anyone tell me where can I find this framework.

Thanks to all,
Madan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be in:
/Developer/Library/Frameworks

I think you also have to install it from. [OCUnit](http://www.sente.ch/software/ocunit/)

Comment: the current versions of the XCode come budled with SenTestKit/OCUnit.  There is no need to download it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Check here on your system -

```
/Developer/Library/Frameworks
```

Comment: Do you mean copying it to the location of other standard frameworks location ? If so, as an admin you can `sudo cp` it. I don't see it as a need as you can add other existing frameworks too to your project through IDE.

Comment: @Mahesh:Yes u right.Actually I am using the Source code of http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/checkout for using google credentials in my app using OAuth and I am getting 2 errors as gFetchCounter and fetchedObject_ are undeclared.I donno where to declare and with which data type .Can u please help me regarding to thi.

Comment: Give the name of the source file in which you are getting these errors.

Comment: So, that I can browse through the online source in the repository.

Comment: @mahesh:Thanks I solved that by importing a file.And I am getting a warning at the line [[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES]; and when I run the apllication Exception is generated at this line.Any idea??

Comment: hi mahesh I am also getting the error in gFetchCounter. can you please help me. How did you solve this error? what file you imported?

Answer (score 0):

Since Xcode 4, this has changed. It is now located in:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/SenTestingKit.framework
```